# Помогите разобраться с Redirections в Bash

Tags: bash

Не совсем разобрался в логике перенаправления.
Допустим у меня есть в корневой директории /root такие файлы

```
ls -l
total 16692
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root   1249479 May  5 22:40 bootstrap-5.0.0-examples.zip
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root       786 May  9 12:49 in
drwxr-xr-x  9 root   root    4096 May  5 16:43 nginx-1.19.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root   1043748 May 26  2020 nginx-1.19.0.tar.gz
drwxrwxr-x 18 root   root      4096 May  5 16:52 openssl-1.1.1g
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root   9801502 Apr 21  2020 openssl-1.1.1g.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root       177 May  9 12:00 out_bash
drwxr-xr-x  9   1169   1169   12288 May  5 16:10 pcre-8.44
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root   2090750 Feb 12  2020 pcre-8.44.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root   2253029 May  7 11:02 v4.0.0.zip
drwxr-xr-x 14    501 staff     4096 May  5 16:18 zlib-1.2.11
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root    607698 Jan 15  2017 zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz
```

Если я выполню

```
bash > out.txt
```

То теперь, если в тойже директории выполнить ls, то ls отобразит пустую директорию!

И чтобы я снова мог видеть свои файлы и деректории мне надо выполнить exit.  При этом в файле out.txt будет содержать список всех моих файлов и каталогов.

Если это возможно, как это можно применить практически?

Comment: Можно сразу сделать `ls -l > out.txt` для получения вывода программы в файл. По этой теме вообще много написано...

Comment: У меня вопрос вообще про другое!

Comment: вопрос ваш (точнее, второй из под-вопросов) именно «про это самое», о чём вам и пишет user7860670 — про практическое применение перенаправления потока вывода.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ls отобразит пустую директорию!

нет, вывод программы, который она отправит в свой stdout, попадёт не к вам на терминал, а будет записано в файл `out.txt`.

---

попробую наглядно продемонстрировать.

вот так выглядят стандартные файловые дескрипторы текущего процесса *bash* (назовём его «процесс номер один») до начала экспериментов:

```
$ ls -ld /proc/$$/fd/{0,1,2}
lrwx------ 1 user user 64 May 10 17:28 /proc/11480/fd/0 -> /dev/pts/7
lrwx------ 1 user user 64 May 10 17:28 /proc/11480/fd/1 -> /dev/pts/7
lrwx------ 1 user user 64 May 10 17:28 /proc/11480/fd/2 -> /dev/pts/7
```

все три (`0` — *stdin*, `1` — *stdout*, `2` — *stderr*) — символические ссылки на `/dev/pts/7` — [устройство псевдо-терминала](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoterminal#Variants), созданное (используемым мной) [эмулятором терминала](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0).

всё, что текущий процесс *bash* (и его потомки) выведет в *stdout* и *stderr*, попадёт в устройство псевдо-терминала, а эмулятор терминала отобразит нам в рисуемом им окне.

выполняя команду `bash > out.txt`, мы запускаем **новый** процесс *bash* (назовём его «процесс номер два»), причём его *stdout* сразу же будет «привязан» к файлу `out.txt`: всё, что этот процесс (и любые порождённые им дочерние процессы) отправит в *stdout*, будет записываться в этот файл.

смотрим, что произошло с файловыми дескрипторами у нового процесса:

```
$ ls -ld /proc/$$/fd/{0,1,2}
```

хм. ничего не видно. ах, да! мы же перенаправили *stdout* в файл `out.txt`. если заглянуть в этот файл из соседнего терминала, то увидим выведенное процессом *ls*:

```
lrwx------ 1 user user 64 May 10 18:01 /proc/22409/fd/0 -> /dev/pts/7
l-wx------ 1 user user 64 May 10 18:01 /proc/22409/fd/1 -> /home/user/out.txt
lrwx------ 1 user user 64 May 10 18:01 /proc/22409/fd/2 -> /dev/pts/7
```

обратите внимание: стандартный дескриптор номер `1` (*stdout*) для выполняемого процесса является ссылкой на файл `out.txt`. именно в этот файл и был записан вывод процесса *ls*, который он отправил в свой *stdout* (который унаследовал от своего родителя — «процесса номер два»).

а если сейчас мы выполним команду `exit`, то завершим работу «процесса номер два», и вернёмся к изначальному состоянию — к «процессу номер один». у которого все три стандартных дескриптора «закреплены» за устройством псевдо-терминалом (обратите внимание на номер процесса — 11480 — он тот же самый, что и в первом листинге):

```
$ ls -ld /proc/$$/fd/{0,1,2}
lrwx------ 1 user user 64 May 10 18:08 /proc/11480/fd/0 -> /dev/pts/7
lrwx------ 1 user user 64 May 10 18:08 /proc/11480/fd/1 -> /dev/pts/7
lrwx------ 1 user user 64 May 10 18:08 /proc/11480/fd/2 -> /dev/pts/7
```

> Если это возможно, как это можно применить практически?

перенаправление потоков ввода-вывода используется буквально повсеместно. берите любой shell-скрипт — практически наверняка увидите в нём и перенаправления.